# Split string inside column into fixed length sub strings

Tags: r, regex, data.table

Here's my mock code and data:

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)

data <- data.table(string = c("aaaaaaaaa", "bbbbbb", "ccccccccccccccc", "aaa"))
data[, length := nchar(string)]

data
            string length
1:       aaaaaaaaa      9
2:          bbbbbb      6
3: ccccccccccccccc     15
4:             aaa      3
```

What i need is to split the "string" column into substrings of length 3. I want the result to be in a separate column, with the substrings separated. I have tried to use a `for` loop in conjunction with `seq`, however this is too slow, as my real data is > 7 million rows.

Here's my for loop with the desired result in a new column.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
  data[i , split := paste(str_sub(string, seq(from = 1, to = length, by = 3),
                          seq(from = 3, to = length, by = 3)), collapse = " - ")]
}
```

Which gives me my desired result - however incredibly slowly.

```
> data
            string length                       split
1:       aaaaaaaaa      9             aaa - aaa - aaa
2:          bbbbbb      6                   bbb - bbb
3: ccccccccccccccc     15 ccc - ccc - ccc - ccc - ccc
4:             aaa      3                         aaa
```

I'm looking for a solution that doesn't use a `for` loop, so i'm guessing it must be `regex` based.

Note that the column `string` may have varying length, but will always be a multiple of 3 and must always be split into groups of 3.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `strsplit` to split strings on every 3 characters and `paste` it into one string.

```
library(data.table)
data[, split := lapply(strsplit(string, "(?<=.{3})", perl=TRUE), 
                paste, collapse = " - ")]

data
#            string                       split
#1:       aaaaaaaaa             aaa - aaa - aaa
#2:          bbbbbb                   bbb - bbb
#3: ccccccccccccccc ccc - ccc - ccc - ccc - ccc
#4:             aaa                         aaa
```

Comment: Could you confirm that `\G...` works as well while `perl` flag is set?

Comment: @revo `strsplit(data$string, "\\G...", perl = TRUE)` gives empty strings

Comment: Maybe that's because it does match characters instead of matching a position?

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with `gsub`

```
data[, split := trimws(gsub("(...)", "\\1 - ", string), whitespace = '[- ]')][]
#             string length                       split
#1:       aaaaaaaaa      9             aaa - aaa - aaa
#2:          bbbbbb      6                   bbb - bbb
#3: ccccccccccccccc     15 ccc - ccc - ccc - ccc - ccc
#4:             aaa      3                         aaa
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this . `(?<=^(...)*)(?!^|$)`. But I don't know if the r language supports it.

[This is a demo on regex101.](https://regex101.com/r/ZyoxNB/2)